# countable subsets of [0,1]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{D \subset [0,1] : |D|\leq |\mathbb{N}| \}$. is $|A| \leq \mathbb{R} ?$.

I tried finding an injection of $A$ into $P(\mathbb{Q})$, but couldn't finish it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D\subset[0,1]$ be countable. We can well order it: $D=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$ where $x_i=0.a_1^ia_2^ia_3^i\dots$ ($a_j^i$ denotes $j^{th}$ digit of $x_i$). The needed function $A\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is $f(D)=0.a_1^1a_2^1a_1^2a_3^1a_2^2a_3^1...$. Move by diagonals of quadrat

$0.a_1^1a_2^1a_3^1\dots\\0.a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2\dots\\0.a_1^3a_2^3a_3^3\dots\\\dots\dots\dots\dots$

Answer (score 1):

As $\vert [0,1] \vert = \vert \mathbb R \vert=\mathfrak c = 2^{\mathbb N}$, you get

$$\vert A \vert = \left( 2^{\mathbb N} \right)^{\mathbb N} = 2^{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N} = 2^{\mathbb N} = \mathfrak c$$